# Not able to append string in ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript's alert

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I want to show alert on the click event of a button in my aspx page where in I want to display the  name of the user who is logged in.

I am trying to do this using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in the following way which i found 
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/518960/AlertplusmessageplusinplusC-net) :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(lnkBtnSaveCart, lnkBtnSaveCart.GetType(), "key", string.Format("alert(Mr/Ms.'{0}' , your cart was saved successfully!);",customerObj.Name ), true);
```

I have put break points to see if the `customerObj` contains the `Name` property or not and it had the necessary name of the logged-in user.

This way works though , but i dont need this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(lnkBtnSaveCart, lnkBtnSaveCart.GetType(), "key", "alert('some message!')", true);
```

Comment: I think your problem is in first formatted alert string. You have to put quotes. If not, probably you are getting some kind of error in the browser because of bad formatted javascript. Please try replacing with this: string.Format("alert(\"Mr/Ms.'{0}' , your cart was saved successfully!\");"...

Comment: what difference does the `\` this make in the start of alert tag ?  Your code did work but it added single quotes around the name .. probably there should be no quotes inside the alert message except at the start and end of the alert message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in your alert message are incorrect. The content within the alert function should be in single quotes. If you need single quotes around the name you will have to escape it. Try this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(lnkBtnSaveCart, lnkBtnSaveCart.GetType(), "key", string.Format("alert('Mr/Ms. {0} , your cart was saved successfully!');",customerObj.Name ), true);
```

Comment: Thank you ! that worked fine! Probably there should be no quotes inside the alert message except at the start and end of the alert message!??

Comment: You can have quotes inside if they are escaped. E.g. Hello \'Praveen\'